# How to add an application as a login item for all users in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-agent

I am trying to add an application as login item for all users by creating an launchd plist and copying it in /Library/LaunchAgents and also by loading it.

Plist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.testapp.UserAgent</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Applications/TestAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/TestAgent</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

RunAtLoad will launch the application at every login.
It is working for me when I login in to all different user accounts in my machine but if I quit it manually then also it is launching by itself.

How can I make it to launch only once for each login and if I quit it then it should not be launched by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The best resource to know how to use `launchd`, the daemon that launches processes on macOS is here:

https://www.launchd.info

In here, it is well explained what other settings you can use apart from `RunAtLoad` or together with it.

For example, in your case, you could use the key `KeepAlive` as follows:

```
 <key>KeepAlive</key>
 <dict>
    <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
    <false/>
 </dict>
```

This would only relaunch your process if it exited with a code different than 0, which normally denotes some abnormal situation or error. If the exit is normal then your process will not be relaunched by `launchd`.

Check the tab `Configuration` on this site to know which other configurations you could use.

Comment: I tried this but still my application is being launched after certain time.More precisely when I login in to my system my launch agent starts the service and application is being launched. After some time I am manually quitting the application and launching it manually later after some time again another instance of application is getting launched. When I check launchctl I see one service with application bundle identifier having pid and this launch agent service with pid

Comment: Please refer my question to see my plist file

Comment: Please remove the RunAtLoad setting. KeepAlive should be enough.

Comment: If RunAtLoad is false then my application will not be launched when user logins

Comment: No, just remove the key RunAtLoad and its value altogether from your plist. Do not set it to false.

Comment: No I am setting it to true <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>